# Telerik RadOrgChart Node click event

Tags: asp.net, telerik

I am working with Telerik Ajax control RadOrgChart

I want to capture when a node was clicked (in fact right clicked) in an OrgChart. I want the event to pass the ID of the node clicked.

I cannot find any such event in OrgChart.

Can anyone please suggest how to do it.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks Ewerton.

I found a better way to do it on client side instead.

Each of the telerik orgchart nodes have default css class, so something like this work:

```
  $telerik.$(".rocItem").click(function (e) {
            var orgChart = $find("<%= RadOrgChart1.ClientID %>");
            var index = orgChart._extractGroupItemFromDomElement(e.target).get_index();
            var hierarchicalIndex = orgChart._extractNodeFromDomElement(e.target)._getHierarchicalIndex();
            hierarchicalIndex = orgChart._getRealHierarchicalIndex(hierarchicalIndex);
            alert("Clicked " + hierarchicalIndex);
        })
```

Comment: Nice cliente solution. In your original question you said "I cannot find any such event in OrgChart", so i (wrongly) assumed you are asking for a server event. In fact, your solution doesnt call any server method, but you can solve this using the ajax API of jQuery. For now you have the two paths to solve your problem, choose the wich one that fits better to your system.

Comment: The hierarchical ID references the 0-based index of the node at each level, so the hierarchical ID of "0:2:1" references the second grandchild of the third child of the first parent. If you want the ID of the node, then call getId() on the results of orgChart._extractNodeFromDomElement(e.target) rather than _get HierarchicalIndex().

Answer (score 1):

Reading the documentation i see that RadOrgChart doesnt have a event handler for node click, so i think you could make your own ItemTemplate and handle the click of the items of the template, something like this.

```
<telerik:RadOrgChart ID="RadOrgChartDirectReports1" EnableViewState="true" Skin="Office2010Silver"
       runat="server">
       <ItemTemplate>  
           <asp:Button CausesValidation = "false" OnClick="LinkButton_Click" CommandArgument='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "EmployeeId")%>'
               runat="server" Text = "Click" ID="LinkButtonNode"></asp:Button>
       </ItemTemplate>           
   </telerik:RadOrgChart>
```

in this example you put a button inside a item, so, you can handle the button click.